# How to pass instruction data in anchor tests?

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

I wrote an anchor program which initializes a counter account and sets its inital value to instruction_data.

```
pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, instruction_data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let counter = &mut ctx.accounts.counter;
        counter.count = instruction_data;
        msg!("Counter account created");
        msg! {"Current count: { }", counter.count};
        Ok(())
    }
```

How can I pass this instruction_data in my test function?

```
  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const tx = await program.methods
      .initialize( 12 )
      .accounts({
        counter: counter.publicKey,
      })
      .signers([counter])
      .rpc();
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
    const account = await program.account["counter"].fetch(counter.publicKey);
    console.log("Count: ", account.count.toNumber());
    expect(account.count.toNumber()).to.eq(0);
  });
```

I don't know in what format I have to pass the instruction_data in the initialize function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to convert the data to BN.

```
  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const tx = await program.methods
      .initialize( new anchor.BN(12) )
      .accounts({
        counter: counter.publicKey,
      })
      .signers([counter])
      .rpc();
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
    const account = await program.account["counter"].fetch(counter.publicKey);
    console.log("Count: ", account.count.toNumber());
    expect(account.count.toNumber()).to.eq(0);
  });
```